# find the slope of the tangent line

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Sorry I couldn't figure out how to use the editor right now and I really need help with this question. 
Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$. find the slope of the tangent line at $(8,\frac{1}{2})$
So far this is what I have I just don't know what to do from here

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
m&=&\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(8+h)-f(8)}{h}\\
&=&\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{8+h}}-1/2}h \\
&=&\lim_{h \to 0} \ 2-\frac{\sqrt[3]{8+h}}{2\sqrt[3]{8+h}}\\
&=&\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2-\sqrt[3]{8+h}}{2h\sqrt[3]{8+h}}\\
\end{array}
$$

Can someone please help me out please

Comment: Have you learned the power rule for derivatives, or do you only know the limit definition of the derivative?

Comment: Rick, you must use latex to write the formula

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I only know the limit definition of the derivative

Comment: @J.W.Perry the 3 is in front of the sqrt its the cube root

Comment: is cubedsqrt(x) $\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^3$ or $\sqrt[3]{x}$

Comment: @Darksonn the second one

Comment: @Darksonn the only thing for the equation with lim h-->0 the -1/2 is not included in the fraction its on the top but after it.
Also with the last one you edited the 2- goes in the numerator and in the denominator it is 2h

Comment: @rick, here is the link to the page for formatting guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Have I formatted it correctly?

Comment: I was just trying to do the last part but I keep doing it wrong the equation under m=    the -1/2 is not part of the 1/cuberoot(8+h) it is still in the numerator but it is after the fraction

Comment: @rick Are you allowed to use L'Hospitals Rule?

Comment: @Darksonn I don't believe so im not sure what that is so I don't think we have learned it yet

Comment: @rick Are you allowed to use the Squeeze Law?

Comment: @Darksonn yes I can use the Squeeze theorem

Comment: @rick see below, for how to do the algebra.

Comment: @Rustyn the first few steps are how my instructor did the problem and I was supposed to go off of that

Comment: @rick alrighty, one sec.

Comment: @rick I edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

From where you're at, do this trick:
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2-\sqrt[3]{8+h}}{2h\sqrt[3]{8+h}}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\left(2-\sqrt[3]{8+h}\right)}{2h\sqrt[3]{8+h}}\frac{\left((8+h)^{2/3} +2(8+h)^{1/3} + 4)\right)}{\left((8+h)^{2/3} +2(8+h)^{1/3} + 4)\right)}=\\
&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-h}{2h(8+h)^{1/3}\left((8+h)^{2/3} +2(8+h)^{1/3} + 4)\right)}= \\
&\lim_{h\to 0} -\frac{1}{2(8)^{1/3}(8^{2/3}+2\cdot8^{1/3}+4)}=-\frac{1}{48}
\end{align*}
Here's an equivalent limit proof.
\begin{align*}
&f'(8)=\lim_{x\to 8}\frac{f(x)-f(8)}{x-8} = \lim_{x\to 8}\frac{\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{2}}{(x^{1/3}-2)(x^{2/3}+2x^{\frac{1}{3}}+4)}= \\
&\lim_{x\to 8} \frac{\frac{2-x^{1/3}}{2x^{1/3}}}{(x^{1/3}-2)(x^{2/3}+2x^{1/3}+4)}=-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 8}\frac{1}{x^{1/3}(x^{2/3}+2x^{1/3}+4)}=\\
&-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2(4+4+4)}\right)=-\frac{1}{48}
\end{align*}

Comment: The argument based on the definition of the derivative uses the fact that $a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$ with $a = 2$ and $b = \sqrt[3]{8 + h}$ to rationalize the numerator.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yup, +1 for your comment. Hopefully that'll make things more clear for the OP.